# Firestore startAt skips the snapshot given to it and behaves as startAfter instead

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a PagingSource that pages through a firestore collection to return documents.

```
class ClipPageDataSource(mParams:Bundle, private val mAds:Boolean):PagingSource<QuerySnapshot, Clip>(), ClipDataSource {

    var query : Query?= null

    private val mFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()

    private var mBaseQuery = mFirestore.collection(SharedConstants.COLLECTION_CLIPS)
        .orderBy("createdAt",Query.Direction.DESCENDING)

    private var mLikedQuery = mFirestore.collection(SharedConstants.COLLECTION_USERS)
        .document(Prefs.getString(SharedConstants.PREF_SERVER_USER_ID,Firebase().getCurrentUserId()))
        .collection(SharedConstants.SUB_COLLECTION_USER_LIKES)
        .orderBy("createdAt",Query.Direction.DESCENDING)

    private var mSavedQuery = mFirestore.collection(SharedConstants.COLLECTION_USERS)
        .document(Prefs.getString(SharedConstants.PREF_SERVER_USER_ID,Firebase().getCurrentUserId()))
        .collection(SharedConstants.SUB_COLLECTION_SAVES)
        .orderBy("createdAt",Query.Direction.DESCENDING)


    val mine = mParams.getBoolean(ClipDataSource.PARAM_MINE)
    val liked = mParams.getBoolean(ClipDataSource.PARAM_LIKED)
    val saved = mParams.getBoolean(ClipDataSource.PARAM_SAVED)
    val user = mParams.getString(ClipDataSource.PARAM_USER)
    val first = mParams.getString(ClipDataSource.PARAM_FIRST)
    val private = mParams.getBoolean(ClipDataSource.PARAM_PRIVATE)

    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<QuerySnapshot, Clip>): QuerySnapshot? {
        return null
    }

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<QuerySnapshot>): LoadResult<QuerySnapshot, Clip> {

        try {
            query = when {
                liked -> {
                    mLikedQuery
                }
                saved -> {
                    mSavedQuery
                }
                else -> {
                    mBaseQuery
                }
            }

            if(mine){
                query = query!!.whereEqualTo("createdBy.uid",Prefs.getString(SharedConstants.PREF_SERVER_USER_ID,Firebase().getCurrentUserId()))
            }else if(user!=null){
                query = query!!.whereEqualTo("createdBy.uid",user)
            }

            query = if (private){
                    query!!.whereEqualTo("private",true)
            }else{
                    query!!.whereEqualTo("private",false)
            }

            first?.let {
                val item = mFirestore.collection(SharedConstants.COLLECTION_CLIPS).document(it).get().await()
                if (item!=null){
                    query = query!!.startAt(item)
                }
                Log.d(TAG,"the first item fetched is ${item.data!!["id"]}")
            }

            query = query!!.limit(15)

            val currentPage = params.key ?: query!!.get().await()

            if (currentPage.size() < 1)
                return LoadResult.Page(emptyList(),null,null)

            val lastDocumentSnapshot = currentPage.documents[currentPage.size() - 1]

            val nextPage = query!!.startAfter(lastDocumentSnapshot).get().await()

            val clips = currentPage.map {
                    it.toObject(Clip::class.java)
                }

            return LoadResult.Page(clips,null,nextPage)

        }catch (e:Exception){
            return LoadResult.Error(e)
        }

    }

    companion object{
        private const val TAG = "DataSource"
    }
}
```

So, in the above code, I have three different collections to fetch data from, and the required one is selected based on the parameters passed.
Now, when I fetch data using the mBaseQuery, and passing an id in first parameter, it returns the data correctly.

But, when I fetch data using the mLikedQuery or the mSavedQuery, instead of returning data from the id passed in first parameter, it uses the next item as the first one. Basically, startAt works as startAfter.

I have checked the snapshot fetched using the id passed in first is correct. So, the block in first?.let, works correctly. But, when the final query is executed, it skips the first item passed in startAt and instead starts from the next item in list.

This only happens with mLikedQuery and mSavedQuery and not with mBaseQuery.
Anybody got any idea what's happening here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DocumentReference` you are providing to `startAt` is always for a document from the collection `SharedConstants.COLLECTION_CLIPS`:

```
val item = mFirestore.collection(SharedConstants.COLLECTION_CLIPS).document(it).get().await()
```

This works fine for your `mBaseQuery` because that query is querying the documents in the `SharedConstants.COLLECTION_CLIPS` collection, however your `mLikedQuery` and `mSavedQuery` are querying documents from different collections so providing a `DocumentReference` from the `SharedConstants.COLLECTION_CLIPS` collection as the `startAt` value here doesn't make sense, the query can't start at a document that doesn't exist in the collection you're querying.

Perhaps you need to set the `item` you provide to `startAt` based on which query is being used, e.g.:

```
...    
first?.let {
        val item = when {
            liked -> {
                mFirestore.collection(SharedConstants.COLLECTION_USERS)
                    .document(Prefs.getString(SharedConstants.PREF_SERVER_USER_ID,Firebase().getCurrentUserId()))
                    .collection(SharedConstants.SUB_COLLECTION_USER_LIKES).document(it).get().await()
            }
            saved -> {
                mFirestore.collection(SharedConstants.COLLECTION_USERS)
                    .document(Prefs.getString(SharedConstants.PREF_SERVER_USER_ID,Firebase().getCurrentUserId()))
                    .collection(SharedConstants.SUB_COLLECTION_SAVES).document(it).get().await()
            }
            else -> {
                mFirestore.collection(SharedConstants.COLLECTION_CLIPS).document(it).get().await()
            }
        }
...
```